# Relay module and Arduino Isolation; How to acheive?

Tags: arduino, relay, isolation

I'm going to control a 3phase motor with an Arduino Pro mini and and a 1 Ch.  relay module. In numerous articles it's been advised to separate Arduino and relay module's Vcc. For sure, the second method is preferred, but does the first method also fulfills this goal?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the diagrams to better illustrate the circuits.

[image]

Comment: What is the main reason in the articles cited?how much current does the relay need?

Comment: the Method 2 diagram is missing a connection between the Pro Mini ground and the relay module ground

Comment: @Umar EMI interference. Relay needs max. 1A.

Comment: @jsotola. Please tell me the reason. I wired the diagram and it works. Why should i connect the grounds together?

Comment: @jsotola any signal should have a return path .. so where the current goes from pro mini to module ? we are also assuming 5v psu is isolated from each other right?

Comment: @jsotola, I updated the diagrams. You can see that JD-VCC is completely separated in method 2.

Comment: More important than the point you are asking about is the TRUE isolation capability of the relay module. ""DO NOT CUT CORNERS** on the low voltage to mains relay . You can buy low cost Asian sourced (usually) relay modules for Arduino and similar use which offer 5V control in to 230 VAC relay contacts. These are usually junk. Often the centre contact(s) of the relays appears on the PCB VERY near the relay coil terminals. LV to mains isolation is poor and disaster always lurks. ALSO many such relays are rated at 10A at 230 VAC. Set up a test rig where failure doesn't matter and try ...

Comment: ... switching 230 VAC 10A repeatedly. :-(. || If using a relay that your system and/or your life depends on, use a relay that is genuinely certified to do the job well. || One good brans is Omron, but there are many others. Asian manufacturers CAM make products as good as the best - but one bought on AliExpress or ebay at astoundingly low prices are not normally included in their quality products. || With AC mains, death may be only mm away for you and your equipment - keep it that way.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, Yeah, these are exactly the possible problems I'm trying to solve in my project. One problem is mentioned above. The other one you said very cleverly.

Comment: Also vital - avoid isolation devices that may have isolation destroyed if the device is destroyed. I had a Hall current sensor handling 50A with 2000V isolation. A battery short delivered enough current to incinerate the internal shunt - connecting 24 V to 5V logic via the carbonised IC. || An opto isolator MUST not fail its isolation if the input circuit is destroyed OR you must NEVER be able to destroy the input circuit. If you have eg 12V in a system, cn it EVER get onto the opto- LED? If it does will the opto LED just fail open or MIGHT the opto incinerate. || If .... ? :-)